# cakephp 3 get property changes entity for dependent model(table)

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to get the result set with extra field through afterFind. In cakePHP no afterFind function. So used `protected function _getAttrName() { 
        return $this->_properties['name'];
    }`

inside the Entity class. But i did not get the output with 'attr_name' property. with find()

```
$this->loadModel('Products');
            $this->loadModel('Attributes');
    // Get the attributes to use as facets
    $attributes = $this->Products->Attributes->find(['all',
                                                        'order' => 'Attributes.id',
                                                        ])
                                                        ->contain(['AttributeTypes'])
                                                            ->where([
                                                                'Attributes.filterable' => true,
                                                                //'Attribute.required' => true,
                                                                ])
                                                                ->hydrate(false)
                                                                    ->toArray();
```

Can i get the solution?

Comment: You don't need `$this->loadModel('Attributes');` in your code here. Since you're accessing Attributes through `$this->Products`, it will be autoloaded for you. Alternately, if you're not using `$this->Products` anywhere else, you can use `$this->loadModel('Attributes');` and then `$this->Attributes->find`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare in your entity class what are the virtual properties you want to expose when converting to array or to json. This is the relevant section of the docs:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#exposing-virtual-properties

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class Product extends Entity
{

    protected $_virtual = ['attr_name'];

    protected function _getAttrName() { 
        return $this->_properties['name'];
    }

    ...
}
```